# (PHP) Go to specific URL if User Input Matches

Tags: php, html

I am trying to setup a form with one input field on my site. If the input is a zip code that matches a zip code in an array of zip codes, then I want the visitor to be taken to a specific url. If the input does not match a zip code in the array, then I want the visitor to be taken to a different url.

So far, here is the code I have:

```
<form class="new_address" id="new_address" method="POST" action="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/zipcodes.php">
          <input placeholder="Enter your zip code here." type="text" id="zipcode" name="zipcode" />
     </div>
     <div class="small-4 columns">
     <input class="button postfix" id="submit" type="submit" value="Book Now" />
     </div>
</form>
```

Here is the zipcodes.php code:

```
    <?php 
    $allowedzips = array("33280", "33180 ", "33160 ", "33154 ", "33161", "33154", "33168", "33261", "33181", "33161", "33166", "33231", "33139", "33055", "33056", "33133", "33134", "33146", "33145", "33145", "33234", "33158", "33114", "33156", "33146", "33124", "33133", "33134", "33143", "33144", "33186", "33190", "33189", "33170", "33157", "33172", "33122", "33147", "33138", "33150", "33030", "33109", "33139", "33034", "33199", "33156", "33160", "33160", "33170", "33015", "33016", "33011", "33010", "33012", "33013", "33018", "33054", "33002", "33014", "33017", "33016", "33018", "33010", "33014", "33015", "33090", "33034", "33033", "33032", "33031", "33035", "33039", "33030", "33092", "33039", "33154", "33158", "33156", "33183", "33173", "33186", "33193", "33196", "33256", "33296", "33176", "33283", "33149", "33161", "33261", "33139", "33030", "33033", "33255", "33178", "33166", "33195", "33110", "33185", "33239", "33238", "33234", "33233", "33231", "33199", "33243", "33196", "33245", "33194", "33193", "33192", "33190", "33189", "33188", "33187", "33153", "33197", "33280", "33299", "33242", "33283", "33184", "33269", "33266", "33265", "33261", "33257", "33256", "33255", "33247", "33296", "33161", "33186", "33167", "33166", "33165", "33164", "33162", "33160", "33159", "33158", "33157", "33156", "33155", "33154", "33163", "33173", "33183", "33181", "33179", "33178", "33177", "33176", "33174", "33172", "33170", "33169", "33168", "33175", "33010", "33180", "33110", "33109", "33107", "33102", "33101", "33055", "33054", "33018", "33017", "33015", "33114", "33136", "33056", "33116", "33122", "33124", "33125", "33126", "33127", "33128", "33129", "33130", "33131", "33132", "33119", "33152", "33182", "33111", "33133", "33134", "33135", "33121", "33146", "33142", "33143", "33141", "33145", "33147", "33014", "33148", "33016", "33150", "33151", "33144", "33149", "33140", "33012", "33011", "33013", "33137", "33138", "33139", "33154", "33141", "33140", "33139", "33119", "33109", "33160", "33239", "33015", "33017", "33018", "33016", "33015", "33014", "33150", "33168", "33167", "33153", "33138", "33161", "33266", "33166", "33030", "33092", "33033", "33032", "33181", "33161", "33180", "33280", "33141", "33261", "33181", "33169", "33168", "33167", "33162", "33161", "33261", "33181", "33180", "33179", "33169", "33161", "33162", "33160", "33180", "33163", "33174", "33265", "33185", "33175", "33165", "33184", "33056", "33055", "33054", "33014", "33015", "33257", "33190", "33157", "33170", "33177", "33187", "33189", "33156", "33256", "33032", "33092", "33190", "33170", "33177", "33189", "33197", "33187", "33031", "33032", "33158", "33176", "33156", "33132", "33176", "33186", "33243", "33256", "33176", "33173", "33183", "33143", "33146", "33155", "33156", "33157", "33183", "33173", "33193", "33140", "33154", "33182", "33194", "33184", "33172", "33174", "33144", "33194", "33162", "33164", "33146", "33124", "33139", "33166", "33183", "33172", "33144", "33155", "33194", "33182", "33174", "33165", "33160");
$input = $_POST["zipcode"];
foreach($input as $zip) {
    if (in_array($zip, $allowedzips)) {
        header('Location: http://localhost:63951/booking');
        exit;
    }
    else {
    header('Location: http://localhost:63951/out-of-range');
    exit;
            }
}
    ?>
```

Where am I going wrong? All I get when I submit the form is the zipcodes.php loading up as a white page.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I don't think you full understand how `foreach()` and `in_array()` work yet. Your problem is simple.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to iterate over `$input` - in fact it doesn't make any sense to. All you need to do is see if `$input` is within your `$allowedzips` array. I also trimmed the user input of extra whitespace with `trim()` just in case:

```
<?php
$allowedzips = array('..','...');
$input = trim($_POST["zipcode"]);
if (in_array($input, $allowedzips)) {
    header('Location: http://localhost:63951/booking');
    exit;
}
else {
    header('Location: http://localhost:63951/out-of-range');
    exit;
}
?>
```